# What is the meaning of a dollar symbol ($) in SciLab?

Tags: scilab

What is the meaning of a dollar symbol ($) in SciLab?

EDIT:
What I meant was dollar symbol used in indexing lists. I assumed that's the single use of it.

Comment: Can you give an example in context?

Answer (score 4):

The dollar symbol can be used to refer to the last element of any vector or matrix.

```
-->A = [1 2 3 4 5]
 A  =

    1.    2.    3.    4.    5.  

-->A($)
 ans  =

    5.  

-->A($-1)
 ans  =

    4.
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://www.scilab.org/product/man/math_rendering_features_in_graphic.html), dollar signs are used to delimit embedded [LaTeX](http://www.latex-project.org/).

> Starting from Scilab 5.2, it is
>   possible to write LaTeX or MathML
>   expression.
>
> LaTeX texts must start and end by $
>   (dollar symbol) while MathML texts
>   must start by < and end by > and being
>   syntactically valide.

Comment: when you are dealing with a string. In a numerical value, it has a different meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently (I found the answer in the meantime), dollar symbol in list indexing means the last element of the list.

```
-->a = list()
 a  =
     ()
-->a(5) = 100
 a  =
// ...
-->a($)
 ans  =
    100.
```

Answer (score 1):

> $ is the pointer to the last index position.

If you are using it on a list, the last index value is returned.
If you are using it on a variable, the last value for the variable is returned.
(It doesn't store any previous instance as history for variables)

```
l = [11,22,33,44,55]
k = 1
k = 2
q = "Saurabh"
disp(l,l($),l($-1))
disp(k,k($))
disp(q,q($))
```

## Output

```
11.   22.   33.   44.   55.

55.

44.

2.

2.

"Saurabh"

"Saurabh"
```

> Please note , k($-1) or q($-1) will give Invalid index.

Answer (score 0):

The first answer is not completely correct. You can user $ as a substitute to the last value of given index, hence using e.g. $-1 or more elaborate expressions is correct:

```
--> x=rand(1,6)
 x  = 

   0.1121355   0.6856896   0.1531217   0.6970851   0.8415518   0.4062025

--> x($-1)
 ans  =

   0.8415518

--> x($/2)
 ans  =

   0.1531217
```